# How to Force IPv4 on apache httpclient? (java)

Tags: java, dns, apache-commons-httpclient

My program always get stuck for 30 seconds on

```
[DEBUG] SingleClientConnManager - Get connection for route HttpRoute[{}->http://foobar.com]
```

Further investigation suggests this is due to ipv4 fallback. 
Is there anyway to force ipv4 on httpclient to resolve the issue?

P.S.
I believe it is a IPv4 problem because `curl -L04 http://foobar.com` is an instantanious download, while `curl -L06 http://foobar.com` produces `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'foobar.com'`

Comment: I can't resolve that hostname either, not to v4 nor v6. Is it an internal-only name server?

Comment: @sarnold, that's just an example ;)  Unfortunately I cannot reveal my client's site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run your program use:

> java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Comment: That's a very google unfriendly string! Now your answer will be immortalised for future Googlers =)   Thanks.